# python : shadow variable type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Since python is a dynamicaly typed language I was expecting it was possible to shadow a variable type hint.

Is it possible to update the type hint of a variable at some point ?

In the following example I was expecting the type of `classes` to become `list[tuple[int, str]] | None` because I change the value in the `if` loop.
I know I can create a new variable for the list, but I prefere the new value to shadow the dict since it's no more neccesary.

So, is it possible to do that without introduce a new variable ?

```py
def foo(classes: Optional[dict[int, str]] = None):
    if classes is not None:
        classes = list(classes.items()) # `classes` type is not updated
        classes.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    a = classes # expecting list[tuple[int, str]] | None, got dict[int, str] | None
```

```bash
> mypy .\foo.py
foo.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[Tuple[int, str]]", variable has type "Optional[Dict[int, str]]")
foo.py:7: error: "Dict[int, str]" has no attribute "sort"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An if statement opens up a new branch and only at runtime we know if classes outside of the loop is None or a list.
Inside the if we theoretically know it but that depends on how thorough the implementation and ast is build for the type hints.

You might can force the type hint update - depends on the lower level implementations though

```
classes : Union[List[Tuple[int, str]], None] # without any declaration after, the loop
```

EDIT: For Spyder the last re-declartion of classes works, but it does not Support Union or Optional. Other IDEs might do
[image]

Comment: With re-declaration I got this error message `Name "classes" already defined on line 4`

Comment: Also for mypy --allow-redefinition?

Comment: With `--allow-redefinition`, if I put the re-declaration just after the `if` loop I don't have `Name "classes" already defined` but I still have `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[Tuple[int, str]]", variable has type "Optional[Dict[int, str]]")`

Answer (score 0):

I found [this blog](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/23/python-type-hints-mypy-doesnt-allow-variables-to-change-type/) that state with MyPy it's not possible to change variable type and the best solution is to create a new variable.